# invalid server name or wildcard in a virtual host in nginx

Tags: nginx, webserver

I have the following virtual host configuration for nginx in a virtual host:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name angularindepth.com
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://blog.angularindepth.com/$1 redirect;
}
```

But when I run nginx it gives me the following errors:

> - [warn] 5007#5007: server name "^/(.*)$" has suspicious symbols in ...
> - [warn] 5007#5007: server name "https://blog.angularindepth.com/$1" has suspicious symbols in ...
> - [emerg] 5007#5007: invalid server name or wildcard "^/(.*)$" on
>     0.0.0.0:80

I've googled and all questions seem to be around `server_name` directive, whereas in my case it contains a proper name. The problem seems to be with `rewrite` directive. Am I right? What's the problem?

Comment: You are missing a terminating `;` after the `server_name` statement.

Comment: oh, yeah,  thanks! I'm not really familiar with the syntax, so it didn't occur to me that semicolon might be the issue